# Excel COUNTIFS Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, countif

I currently have two columns with dates in them, i am trying to use the COUNTIFS to check that if the first date is greater than the second date, count up.

i currently have this but it does not work:

```
=COUNTIFS('CDT DWGS-2014'!F:F,2014,'CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S,"<>",'CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q,">" &'CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S)
```

I do not know what is wrong and i have been looking on the web for a while now, but i can't seem to find what is wrong.

Is there another way to go about doing this?

Thank you

Comment: what, exactly, are you trying to achieve? if you're only looking at the first date and comparing it to the second date, you don't need `countifs`. you just need a simple if: `if(firstDate > secondDate, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a "one to one" column comparison with `COUNTIFS`, try `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(('CDT DWGS-2014'!F:F=2014)*('CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S<>"")*('CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q>'CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S))`

....but I recommend you use specific ranges rather than whole columns otherwise that will be slow

Comment: Hi Barry, You are VERY VERY CLOSE to what i need! The only thing missing is that i want the above code with *('CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q>="1-Jan-14")*('CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q<"1-Feb-14")     But that doesn;t seem to work, why?

Comment: In that context "1-Jan-14" isn't recognised as a date, either use +0 like *('CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q>="1-Jan-14"**+0**)*('CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q<"1-Feb-14"**+0**) or use DATE function like DATE(2014,1,1)